# How to identify a user who bought the application?

Tags: android

I would like to in my application user can download content on http, but without having to log on.

how to check whether the request to the server came with the purchased android application?

PS. Sorry for terrible english.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be easily handled by Android [LVL library](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html). In brief it works in following way:

1. Once user purchase application LVL library can get through
   Android Market application service response from Android market
   server that application is licensed
2. Application itself can store in local file system hash of licensing server
   response

So your application can use those hash to identify whether application is purchased or not yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using single APK for free and paid , you must be using in app billing API .so use it for server authentication also .

else if it is only one APK on market then every installation would be purchased one i  guess .

Answer (score -1):

I would generate a some kind of key for the premium version (one key for all the premium version). For example:

You are allowed to download (premium):

`http://www.myurl.com/download.php?parameter1=xxx&key=myPremiumVersionKey`

You are not allowed to download because no key/wrong key is given (free version):

`http://www.myurl.com/download.php?parameter1=xxx`